# What does this JetBrains keyboard shortcut icon mean?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, symbols, jetbrains-ide

I'm looking at the keyboard shortcuts for code folding in PHPStorm. Their [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-folding.html) and the keymapping settings for these commands show this weird grey symbol, see here:

[image]

I have no idea what this refers to - does anyone have any idea what the default keyboard shortcuts for these commands are on OSX?

Comment: The "grey symbol" must be the numeric pad. In your context it means the "star on num pad" -- `Command + Num Pad *` and then `1`

Comment: Joy! So that's what it is! Thanks a lot, this works. Stick this in answer if you like and i'll tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "grey symbol" means numeric pad.

In your specific context it means the "star on num pad" key -- so the first shortcut would be `Command + Num Pad *` and then `1`.